# Cannot correctly rename source file in Gradle/NDK project

Tags: android, c++, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle NDK test project, with a Java file and a C file, developed under Android Studio.

It builds and runs as it should.

Now I would like to rename the C file from `plasma.c` to `plasma.cpp`. I do it with the refactoring/rename menu command. From it I get no warning, I confirm the refactoring, I resync the project, and I rebuild it.

When I launch the executable on the device, I get an error message ("Unfortunately Plasma has stopped"), and from the logs:

> No implementation found for void
>   com.example.plasma.PlasmaView.renderPlasma(android.graphics.Bitmap,
>   long) (tried Java_com_example_plasma_PlasmaView_renderPlasma and
>   Java_com_example_plasma_PlasmaView_renderPlasma__Landroid_graphics_Bitmap_2J)

I made a search on all the project for the string "plasma.", and noticed that the substitution has been correctly done in all the source files and in `.idea/workspace.xml`.

Why renaming a C++ source file in the project causes the executable to crash?

Comment: try doing a project clean before doing a rebuild..

Comment: I'm not sure why this would happen either, but I'd try uninstalling and reinstalling your app.

Comment: @Pietro did you find a solution? I have similar problem.

Comment: @Lucky_girl: I am afraid not; I moved on a different project in the meantime...